# Setting Up and Managing Thin Client

Tags: thin-client

I have taken delivery of fairly used HP thin clients with model no t5730w.

I am trying to use it set up a computer laboratory for a school in a remote part of Ghana, Africa that I volunteered for.

I am able to connect one device to the host/server I have set up but anytime I connect it via RDP, the Host will have to be locked.

Meanwhile I assumed I will have to create multiple user account on the Host and connect one thin-client to one account. But if the first device locks the host how am I able to connect the rest?

Is there a straight forward way to have this set up and also not lock the terminals?

Is there any form of management software (probably free because I am funding everything out of my own pocket) to make this easy since i will be leaving and have to train someone to manage the set up once I'm not around.

I am fairly familiar with networking and computers but haven't worked with thin-clients before. Honestly the cost of setting this up might have not be that much different from fat-client but I'm concerned about the electricity bills they will have to incur subsequently.

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks,
Max

Comment: `I am able to connect one device to the host/server I have set up but anytime I connect it via RDP, the Host will have to be locked.` Is this "host/server" a Desktop Windows installation by chance, not a Windows Server with terminal server licenses?

Comment: Yes, it is a desktop windows installation not a Windows Server with terminal server licenses.

Comment: there's your problem - you only get 1 concurrent user. - Is the school registered? - MS will help you out with this, I urge you to make contact with their academic representatives in Africa, keep up the good work!

Comment: Right. I will do just that. Thanks very much for your kind words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a Desktop Windows as Terminal Server. It's technical impossible (only one RDP connection is allowed and it **will** lock the current desktop session) and also prohibited by the license terms.

You need either to get your hand on a legal Windows Server license with enough TS CALs or need to investigate other options like Linux terminals (e.g. LTSP).

Comment: oo ok. That makes a lot of sense and understandable. But is the license for the TS CALS sold separately or it comes with certain levels of the Server license. I am looking into having 20 devices connected max. 

But can't see what the price will get to by looking at the windows server licensing page from microsoft. https://www.microsoft.com/en/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2012-r2/purchasing.aspx

Comment: In your case, you need to contact either MS or an authorized reseller to get a quote for your actual situation. The very specific use case might play a role in this.

Comment: right. Thanks very much. I really appreciate your prompt responses. Good day sir.